# Https - CSS / JS / Images now blocked

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to SSL certificates, but I've just installed one on my site.

I link to my CSS, JS, Images etc like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

However it is now blocked as coming from an unsecure location.

If I change it to this, it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://...com/css/style.css">
```

Is there a way to force "css/style.css" to be secure? Or do I have to rewrite some portions of my code?

Any help appreciated thanks

Comment: You don't need to use an absolute URL, as the two answers (wrongly) suggest. If you called the main page via HTTPS, then a relative URL such as `css/style.css` is resolved to an absolute HTTPS URL automatically. Why this doesn't work in your case, is impossible to say without seeing a live example. (Maybe some kind of redirect back to HTTP is happening, for whatever reason.)

Comment: Or are you by any chance using the `base` element inside your HTML? If that is set to an HTTP URL, then that would of course screw up the automatic resolving of relative URLs to HTTPS.

Comment: CBroe you genius it was the base element that was throwing things off, I completely forgot about that! I changed it and everything worked! Thanks - if you write it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use an absolute URL, as the two previous answers (wrongly) suggest. If you called the main page via HTTPS, then a relative URL such as `css/style.css` is resolved to an absolute HTTPS URL automatically. <del>Why this doesn't work in your case, is impossible to say without seeing a live example.</del>

Are you by any chance using the `base` element inside your HTML? If that is set to an HTTP URL, then that would of course screw up the automatic resolving of relative URLs to HTTPS.

---

Turns out you did have a `base` element, and it was the culprit.